# Firefox Web Extension "selectionchange"

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to write cross browser Web Extension.

Based on selected value on web page I want to create appropriate entry in context menu. I created a sample code to check if browser is entering to Event Listener. In Chrome it's all working fine, but in firefox following code is not being executed.

```
console.log("Content script entry");
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function() {
    debugger;
    console.log("CS Add Event");
 });
```

Could you please help?

Best regards

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `selectionchange` is still hidden behind a flag in Firefox... open up `about:config` and search for `dom.select_events.enabled` ... it defaults to `false`, change it to `true` and restart the browser and give it another whirl.