# Is it possible to get selectionchange-like events for an input box in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

### How can I get the selected text inside an `input` box in Firefox?

This is apparently a fundamental difference in the way that JavaScript works between Chrome and Firefox. To reproduce:

- Navigate to www.google.com
- Open JS console
- Type following line: `document.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => console.log(document.getSelection().toString()))`
- Type "text" into Google search box and do **not** hit enter
- Use the mouse to select different portions of the "text" in the search box

In Chrome, you will see the event raised for selected text within the `input` element. This is consistent across various web pages that use `input` fields. In Firefox, the event is raised for selections outside the `input`, but when the text in the box is selected, no event is raised.

I have not found any explicit reference to this difference in any Mozilla documentation, nor have I found mention of it on any other web page.

## Related but different question

[Firefox Web Extension “selectionchange”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059087/firefox-web-extension-selectionchange) is an older question, and the `dom.select_events.enabled` config attribute is now defaulted to `true` in FF 56. There is a second config attribute, `dom.select_events.textcontrols.enabled` that seems like what I'm looking for, but changing that value to `true` doesn't seem to have any effect.

## Additional info (Edit 1)

Apparently there isn't even a way to get selected text in a textbox in FF? The following code also doesn't work:

```
setInterval(() => console.log(document.getSelection().toString()), 1000)
```

In FF, this will never return the selected text in an input field. In Chrome, it will.

Is this just a feature gap in FF? Is there no other way to extract selected text from a form field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox Web Extension "selectionchange"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059087/firefox-web-extension-selectionchange)

Comment: Thanks. It's not exactly the same thing. I wasn't aware of that config, but it is apparently already defaulted to `true` in FF 56. There's apparently another config setting, `dom.select_events.textcontrols.enabled` which is defaulted to `false`. I tried toggling it, but it doesn't seem to change the behavior. It's not limited to events, though. I apparently can't even get the selected text in a text control. I will update the question with more details.

Comment: NVM. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809197/3119991) will work, I guess. It's just more complicated.

Comment: `dom.select_events.textcontrols.enabled` needs to be set to true in about:config.

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting dom.select_events.textcontrols.enabled in firefox did not enable `document.addEventListener("selectionchange"...` events for within textarea changes, but what it enabled was `<textarea onselectionchange="...">`.

By adding your handler to both, and toggling that firefox flag, you should get something that works in Chrome, Safari, and Edge (through document selectionchange) and in Firefox (through textarea onselectionchange).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to detect `document.onselectionchange` events from inputs or textareas in Firefox (86), but I *am* able to detect `select` events **from the textareas themselves** (`onselect`).

(Thanks to [this post](https://quares.ru/?id=234794) [in Russian] for the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809197/3119991) I have been able to create the following:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    selection = getSelectedText();
});


function getSelectedText() {
    let elem = document.activeElement;
    let elemType = elem ? elem.tagName.toLowerCase() : 'none';
    if (elemType === 'input' || elemType === 'textarea') {
        return elem.value.substr(elem.selectionStart, elem.selectionEnd - elem.selectionStart);
    }

    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    }

    if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== 'Control') {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
```

My testing so far shows that this seems to work well for both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This obviously doesn't work when the selection is set or changed with the keyboard.